# Vue-router. Как вызвать remount в router-view?

Tags: vue.js, роутинг

есть select от id опции которого надо вызывать один и тотже компонент который подключен через router-view

Comment: Можно код, или подробнее разъяснить вопрос, я вообще не понял что к чему

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо передавать value у option в prop компонента

```
<comp v-bind:some-prop="1"></comp>
```